# requestAnimationFrame Refresh Rate

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I'm using requestAnimationFrame to draw players in my game. One of the players is moving faster than everybody else. I did some checking with him and he told me that his monitor has a 120hz refresh rate. I'm assuming this means has can process frames faster than others resulting in faster movement speed. Any ideas as to how I can get around this?

Thanks

The shim layer used is below:

```
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

Comment: Don't put game logic in your draw loop. Your draw code should simply poll the game state, which is updated in a separate loop.

Comment: Also, a 120Hz refresh rate is the rate that *physical monitor* can update its pixels. The rate at which the user's browser can update its draw state will probably be much slower, and it is likely bounded by CPU performance, memory, bus speeds, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. I do have 2 loops, one for drawing and one for updating game logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed framerate. However, you can force an approximate framerate using a simple timer: [How to solve different FPS in requestAnimationFrame on different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681738/how-to-solve-different-fps-in-requestanimationframe-on-different-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

`requestAnimationFrame` has no guaranteed rate. It could fire at 2Hz if it wanted to.

You need to make your game loop function independent of time between calls. Most games do this by calculating the number of milliseconds that pass between rendering steps, and then animating game objects based on how much time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Think of requestAnimationFrame as an opportunity to update/redraw. You should still base the update process on how much time has passed.

For instance, if a player can move 100px in 1 second and RAF is firing every .1 seconds you need to update 10px every time

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the `requestAnimationFrame` has no guaranteed rate, but you could measure the time difference between `requestAnimationFrame` calls using it's callbacks' timestamp argument, and then creating an animation that calculates what should have occurred in that length of time.

This CodePen link shows an example of that https://codepen.io/sassano/pen/wvgxxMp.